# Javascript - Remove CSV Item At Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, csv

I have made a simple function to remove a csv item at the set index however it only removes the item and keeps the comma (,) like:

",B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z"

when given the string:

"A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z"

I need to know how to correct this function so it removes the comma also.

My function:

```
function RemoveCSVItem(csv, item) {
    var csvarray = csv.split(",");
    delete csvarray[item];
    return csvarray;
}
```

Comment: http://jsh.zirak.me/saip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use splice to remove the item and (condense the remaining)

```
function removeCSVItem(csv, idx) {
    var csvarray = csv.split(",");
    csvarray.splice(idx, 1);
    return csvarray;
}
```